# An Error when trying to open an order in the Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, error

```
Magento 1.9.1.0
Porto theme 
Apache Version  2.4.25 
MySQL Version 5.6.35 
PHP Version 5.5.38
```

It worked well forever. I made no changes on my end whatsoever except installed a new version of the calendar by BSSCommerce and Full Page Cache from Amasty. This was all done about a week ago and it worked fine.

I tried everything - restarted mySQL, restarted Apache, rebooted the server (4x). Cleared all Cache (from withing the Admin and also renamed the folder via FTP), re-indexed, disabled Cache, tried to disable the Full Page Cache by Amasty (how do you correctly do that?), tried disabling the calendar. All to no avail.

> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where
>   clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `mg_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN
>   `mg_sales_flat_order` ON main_table.increment_id =
>   mg_sales_flat_order.increment_id WHERE (increment_id LIKE '%3983%')

**EDITED: I placed a test order, then click on SALES --) ORDERS and I get the following Error:**

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mg_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `mg_sales_flat_order` ON main_table.increment_id = mg_sales_flat_order.increment_id WHERE (increment_id LIKE '%3991%')

Trace:
#0 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(516): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(563): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/local/Bss/Deliverydate/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php(35): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Bss_Deliverydate_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/mySITE/pu...')
#21 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/mySITE/pu...')
#32 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#40 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /home/mySITE/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}
```

### **Error log record number: 979287499550**

### EDITED again: In the cpanel of my account it currently shows the PHP Version    5.6.30 while I could almost swear it was php5.5 before. **Could this be the problem?** UPDATE: According to the hosting company - I have PHP Version 5.5.38.

When I open one of the files referenced in the Error message - it has the following Error inside:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:311:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mg_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `mg_sales_flat_order` ON main_table.increment_id = mg_sales_flat_order.increment_id WHERE (increment_id LIKE '%3991%')";i:1;s:5634:"#0 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(516): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /home/mySITE/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(563): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/local/Bss/Deliverydate/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php(35): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Bss_Deliverydate_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/mySITE/pu...')
#21 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/mySITE/pu...')
#32 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#40 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /home/mySITE/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /home/mySITE/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/index.php/hillegom/sales_order/index/key/a93767a4ea2a49cb2140105a02d152d3/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a phpinfo.php file in your Magento root folder with the contents

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Browse to http://yoursite/phpinfo.php

Whilst not the solution this will tell you exactly what the MySql version running on the server is. A mysql upgrade could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bss_Deliverydate module is joining `sales_flat_order` table to the grid table without properly adding labels for each table. Try disabling Bss_Deliverydate module and see if that is the case. If so ask the vendor to fix the issue or try to fix it yourself inside `/home/mySITE/public_html/app/code/local/Bss/Deliverydate/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php` file. If the license of the module permits you can post `prepareCollection` method from that class here so we can show you what is wrong with it.